# Get parent directory in Ansible?

Tags: path, yaml, ansible

Is there a way to evaluate a relative path in Ansible?

```
tasks:
  - name: Run docker containers
    include: tasks/dockerup.yml src_code='..'
```

Essentially I am interested in passing the source code path to my task. It happens that the source code is the parent path of `{{ansible_inventory}}` but there doesn't seem to be anything to accomplish that out of the box.

---- further info ----

Project structure:

```
myproj
  app
  deploy
    deploy.yml
```

So I am trying to access `app` from `deploy.yml`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the `dirname` filter:

```
{{ inventory_dir | dirname }}
```

For reference, see *[Managing file names and path names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)* in the docs.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question a bit to show what I am looking for. I need the parent of `inventory_dir` as a full path.

Comment: Also `| dirname | dirname` syntax seems to work for grandparent directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{{playbook_dir}}` for the absolute path to your current playbook run. 
For me thats the best way, because you normally know where your playbook is located.

Comment: @fixPeters How to go to 1 step before i.e. parent directory of {{Playbook_dir}} ?

Comment: @bosari "{{playbook_dir}}/.."

Answer (score 0):

OK, a workaround is to use a separate task just for this:

```
tasks:
  - name: Get source code absolute path
    shell: dirname '{{inventory_dir}}'
    register: dirname
  - name: Run docker containers
    include: tasks/dockerup.yml src_code={{dirname.stdout}}
```

Thanks to udondan for hinting me on `inventory_dir`.